# Solve the differential equation IVP

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve $\displaystyle x \frac{dy}{dx} = 2y + x^2, y(1) = 2$

We can use the homogeneous form, $y = vx$, so $dy/dx = xdv/dx + v$

$x^2dv/dx + vx = 2x(v + x) \implies x^2 dv/dx = vx + x \implies x dv/dx = v + 1 \implies (v+1) dv = xdx \implies v^2/2 + v = x^2 + C$

Then we would just substitute $v = y/x$

But is there a simpler method?

Comment: Your equation isn't homogeneous !

Answer (score 2):

If, instead, you start using $$y=x^2z\implies y'=2xz+x^2z'$$ the equation becomes$$x^2 \left(x z'-1\right)=0$$ which looks quite simple.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an integrating factor:

$$x\frac{dy}{dx}=2y+x^2\implies \frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{2}{x}\cdot y=x,\quad x\neq 0$$

Then $$I=e^{\int-\frac{2}{x}}dx =e^{-2\ln x}=e^{\ln(x^{-2})}=\frac{1}{x^2}$$

$$\implies \frac{1}{x^2}\cdot y=\int x\cdot \frac{1}{x^2} dx$$

$$\frac{y}{x^2} = \ln x +c$$

$$y(1) = 2\implies 2=0+c\implies c=2$$

$$\implies y=x^2(\ln x +2)$$

Comment: Apparently $y(1)=2$.

Comment: @CheeHan Hm strange, perhaps I misred it, anyways edited.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray}
xy'&=&2y+x^2\\
x^2y'-2xy&=&x^3\\
\dfrac{x^2y'-2xy}{x^4}&=&\dfrac{1}{x}\\
\left(\dfrac{y}{x^2}\right)'&=&\dfrac{1}{x}\\
\int\left(\dfrac{y}{x^2}\right)'&=&\int\dfrac{1}{x}\\
\dfrac{y}{x^2}&=&\ln x+C\\
y&=&x^2\ln x+2x^2
\end{eqnarray}